# Android Create a ListView containing a variable number of columns containing TextViews

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I have successfully managed to create my UI with a variable number of columns of data for displaying and inputting data.
Now to do the same for my ListView

The ListView listXYVals is defined in the following manner (I have omitted irrelevant elements):

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/displayValues"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/listXYVals"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="top"  
  android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The program then processes the information by referencing **R.layout.xy_list_item** defining a fixed number of items that are displayed in columns:

```
 ListView m_listView = (ListView)
 m_thisView.findViewById(R.id.listXYVals);
 m_adapter = new InputNewDataAdapter(m_parentActivity, **R.layout.xy_list_item**,
        m_rowItems);
```

I have been struggling to find a way to replace the reference to **xy_list_item.xml** with its fixed number of columns by a dynamically created LinearLayout containing a variable number of items. I can create a LinearLayout object with the required members, but then don't know how to pass the information to the ArrayAdapter. Part of the problem is knowing how to articulate the question. I think that if I could create my own resource dynamically, all would be solved, but that may not make sense.
Information about a strategy would be helpful.

David Butland

Comment: If what you're looking for is how to create a ListView with a custom adapter, you might want to take a look here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom

Comment: In getView() you can simply set the visibility of your text views.